# Is it possible to add a click event to a canvas tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, click, offset

I've created a:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktf3fzbx/20/)

**Question:**  How can I get the offset position to register onClick of a canvas Tag?

**Problem:**  Click on Image tag console.log works fine.  Click on canvas and nothing :c
**HTML:**

```
<img id="rando" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="" >
<canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("rando");
var pos = {};
c.width = 400;
c.height = 200;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

 $('img').click(function(e) {
        var posX = $(this).offset().left,
            posY = $(this).offset().top;

        console.log((e.pageX - posX)+ ' , ' + (e.pageY - posY));
    });

 $('c').click(function(e) {
        var posX = $(this).offset().left,
            posY = $(this).offset().top;

        alert((e.pageX - posX)+ ' , ' + (e.pageY - posY));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the '

```
$(c).click(function(e) {
...
 });
```